# jQuery val() issue in Firefox/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, javascript-framework

I am trying to access textbox value using the jQuery code;

```
$("#pg_textbox").val();
```

But it does not return the correct value in Firefox/Safari..

Even

```
$("#paging_textbox").attr("value")
```

does not work..

In firefox debugger, it kind of says `keyCode = 13, ..`.

But I want the actual value entered by the user..
Please help me. Thank you.

*Updated code

HTML

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" size="2" value="1" id="paging_textbox">
```

JS

```
textValue = $("#paging_textbox").attr("value");
alert(textValue);
```

Comment: is it a textarea or an input field (type=text)? try to point the selector more precisely: $('textarea#pg_textbox').val() ?

Comment: Are you sure that the selector is correct? In your example above you're showing two different selectors.

Comment: Seems you using wrong selector.. Try to review page source and find textbox with id = pg_textbox, or check it at firebug.

Comment: The id is correct in the page..It just was a copy/paste error over here...So it is a textbox having code as <input type="text" maxlength="5" size="2" value="1" id="paging_textbox">

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: keyCode 13 is the enter (or carriage return) key. It sounds like the event it firing after you use that key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the id/name of your text box.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="textbox" id="pg_textbox" name="pg_textbox" value="Hello!" />
<input type="button" id="GetValue" name="GetValue" value="Get Value" />
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#GetValue").click(function() {
  alert( $("#pg_textbox").val() ); 
});
```

Try to check this sample on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeC2X/).

Comment: so, the name of your textbox is paging_textbox, then? Have you tried with FireBugs to do some debugging? Are you sure you do not have page errors (scripts)? Could you put some sample code somewhere so we can have a look?

Comment: So in the debugger it says "charCode = 0, keyCode = 13, ..."

Comment: So instead of returning what the user has entered say "01", it returns this in Firefox...works fine in IE though..Also when I alert , it says [object KeyboardEvent] for textValue = $("#paging_textbox").attr("value");

Comment: @hmthr: I think you have to show some script here.It seems to me that you're doing something wrong :-s

Comment: It would be helpful to see the whole script. Anyway, try to print your jQuery version: alert($().jquery);

Comment: There is nothing much except what I have given here..Also jQuery version is v1.3.2

Comment: So assume the page has only 1 textbox as I have given and there is a button onclick of which I call the JS code given by me..

Comment: That's exactly what I've done here http://jsfiddle.net/qeC2X/1/ and it works with 5 different browsers. Try to change your script the way I did var textValue = $("#paging_textbox").val(); and tell me what happened. If it doesn't work try to publish your page somewhere so can try and debug it.